# Android WebView-based browsers not able to access protected resources through Oracle Access Manager (OAM)

Tags: android, oracle, webview, single-sign-on

We have a website that makes use of OAM for single sign on (form-based authentication). When we submit credentials to WebGate / Access Server the authorization succeeds, however after the authentication is performed, the form action (as configured in the Authentication Scheme - with passthrough:no) returns a server error instead of redirecting to the originally requested URL.

If we use Mini Opera, we are able to get authenticated and forwarded properly.

This problem happens on numerous Android phones (versions ranging from 1.5-2.2), as well as the Emulator provided with the SDK.

This is proving to be a real problem as the default browser on Android phones is not able to get access to our sites(and this is the only browser that is having this problem).

I have created a WebView-based custom browser with the hope of seeing a client-side error and tried trapping every possible error....none show up....

I have tried to trace all of the http requests and found only a single difference in the requests... the http header for Connection:keep-alive is not sent by the Android WebView.

I have provided some tracing info below...

Has anyone run into this problem? Has anyone solved this?
Any insight to this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Tim

Request RAW Data-

- POST
  http: // MYSERVER/security/ATLAFunction HTTP/1.1 Host: MYSERVER:7777
  Accept-Encoding: gzip
  Accept-Language: en-US
  Cookie:ObSSOCookie=loggedoutcontinue
  Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1,utf-16, *;q=0.7

  Referer:http://10.84.32.71:7777/tpf/login.html

  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; sdk Build/FRF42) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

  Origin: http: // MYSERVER

  Accept:application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Content-Length: 27
  uname=auser&pwd=appas

Raw Response Data -

- HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily
  Unavailable
   Date: Tue, 05 Oct
  2010 14:26:12 GMT
   Set-Cookie:
  ObSSOCookie=II%2F4n5pFreT6B6hOAumv6pI6CZh6l04VhyXHrCzuRUT5hDEHMK%2FJCX659uyCkxgIyJ8ywB3BKrHxorsCwZwivpn91t9Mu%2FCKT7PrY23S518xoBeOam26tr%2B0pSfCbo%2FZXLmFIxjHFOPHPGxi5tHrOlUroXXA9Fe0GZz3SbJLMgAkCw0euuAVewOHKIjoDh8MwAdGtL4lo%2BmHhk5kB316iFJ4Aljr7cQYpAp1r%2BVGD9FbLkYl4ekY5hrlNfwYS%2BVjnR0uSIFjc0toiKkGN33z7%2FiElh2Ue2iWQrpCRcgFpxE%3D;
  httponly; path=/;
   Cache-Control:
  no-cache
   Pragma: no-cache
  Content-Length: 312
   Connection:
  close
   Content-Type: text/html;
  charset=iso-8859-1

  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC
  "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
  <html><head>
  <title>503 Service Temporarily
  Unavailable</title>
  </head><body>
  <h1>Service Temporarily
  Unavailable</h1>
  <p>Sorry!The server is
  currently unable to handle the
  request
   due to a temporary
  overloading or maintenance of the
  server.</p>
  </body></html>

Comment: Tim, I'm setting up an OAM protected Java EE 6 site.  Do you have any good links to sites detailing configuration and example code?

Comment: Hi Tim, can you share webgate logs for a single request.